# Reply Address Mismatch in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, office365, heroku-toolbelt

I have deployed an app to Heroku and I am getting the following error

The reply address 'https://mighty-wildwood-99148.herokuapp.com/authorize' does not match the reply addresses configured for the application:

This error comes up on attempting to login to the Microsoft Office 365

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this for OAuth?

Answer (score 0):

Some more information would help, but it sounds like it's saying that specific url needs to be "authorized" or whitelisted in the consuming app, presumably Office 365. So somewhere in the Office preferences, there should be a list of authorized urls. Add this url to that list.

It *may* be Application Properties in Azure AD. specifically, setting the Reply Url property. But I'm just guessing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/get-started-with-office-365-management-apis